# Could not authenticate you from GoogleOauth2 because "Invalid credentials"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, google-oauth, omniauth

I params the Google subscription with the gem `'omniauth-google-oauth2'` and I config the ui and provider + in the devise.rb I put this code `config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_SECRET"], scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email, first_name,last_name', image_size: 'large'`

I enter the code in application.yml and I generate contacts APIs + Google + APIs but when I want to connect it like this : [image: click here : autorisation]
the error message tells me that [image: "Csrf detected"]
Please could you tell what's wrong. Your help is appreciated.

I am a little bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

In your callback controller you can add:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently got this same error using the `omniauth-google-oauth2` gem:

> Could not authenticate you from GoogleOauth2 because “Invalid credentials”

The server logs showed this:

> OAuth2::Error {"code"=>403, "message"=>"Legacy People API has not been used in project 1070582368186 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=############# then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."

As discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/379) I upgraded the gem to the latest version (`0.8.0`) which fixed it. Here is the [commit](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/commit/e3cbdc512a020249e201300df01ed4ddde78d176) that performs the workaround.

Answer (score -1):

I was also having the same issue but with my Rails app. So I resolved it by upgrading the omniauth gems by running bundle update devise omniauth omniauth-google-oauth2 in terminal.
Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62572976/15751045