# mongo db data writing issue - oauth

Tags: node.js, mongodb, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

i am trying to create an oauth for a website. no collections have been created in the mongodb.
this is my function to write data:

```
User.findOne({googleId: profile.id}).then((currentUser) => {

        if(currentUser){
            // already have this user
            console.log('user is: ', currentUser);
            done(null, currentUser);
        } else {
            console.log('DEBUG Login');
            // if not, create user in our db
            new User({
                googleId: profile.id,
                username: profile.displayName,
                thumbnail: profile._json.image.url
            }).save().then((newUser) => {
                console.log('created new user: ', newUser);
                done(null, newUser);
            });
        }
    });
```

This is my user-model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    googleId: String,
    thumbnail: String
});

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: What's the error? What output do you get? Please add those for better clarification

Comment: This is the error message after clicking on gmail account: GooglePlusAPIError: Legacy People API has not been used in project 423402557336 before or it is disabled.  But the api is enabled in developer console.

Comment: After refreshing the error page i am getting:  TokenError: Bad Request

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59753790/7482427)

Comment: It's not working. And also i am getting a deprecation warning.

Comment: @ShivamSood in the answer you linked, someone commented at the end that google + api has been completely decommissioned for new projects. If that's so then is there a new API?