# Legacy People API has not been used in project

Tags: php, api, google-api-php-client

I am getting error when calling google sign in API. Error is

> "Legacy People API has not been used in project ************ before or it is disabled"

But the people API is enable. How to solve this error ?

This is my google api url is this is sufficient to solve my problem

```
if (empty($_POST['google_key'])) {
        $error_code    = 5;
        $error_message = 'google_key (POST) is missing';
    } else {
        $app_key = $_POST['google_key'];
        // https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token={$access_token}&key={$app_key}
        $get_user_details = fetchDataFromURL("https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?access_token={$access_token}&key={$app_key}");
        $json_data = json_decode($get_user_details);
        if (!empty($json_data->error)) {
            $error_code    = 4;
            $error_message = $json_data->error;
        } else if (!empty($json_data->id)) {
            $social_id = $json_data->id;
            $social_email = $json_data->emails[0]->value;
            $social_name = $json_data->displayName;
            if (empty($social_email)) {
                $social_email = 'go_' . $social_id . '@google.com';
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my code where m using app key as google key and the access token now explain me where's the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [403 Message: Legacy People API has not been used in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645078/403-message-legacy-people-api-has-not-been-used-in-project)

Comment: @Christoph this question is tagged PHP which implies the author is using php the duplicate you are mentioning is C#.     Do you still think its a duplicate?

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] specifically your authorization code and the method you are trying to call.

Comment: @DaImTo I did a quick research and as far as I can tell this problem is specific to the API, not to the programming language. It's more about using the correct endpoints than implementing them. The answers in the linked questions are not specific to c# either, so I figured it might be a duplicate.

Comment: When editing your question dont remove the existing text that changes the context of the question.    If you have a new question open a new question.

Comment: Why are you not following the official [PHP quickstart](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/php) ?   I cant tell you where you are getting that access token from the API key should be comming from the google cloud console when you created your project.

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is that it says `legacy people api`, this often means you are trying to use one of the old [Google+](https://support.google.com/googlecurrents/answer/9217723?hl=en) scopes.

A lot of the profile related endpoints that where once part of the google+ api were moved to the [People api](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest) after the shutdown of [Google+](https://support.google.com/googlecurrents/answer/9217723?hl=en) .

As you can see by the endpoint you are calling you are trying to use the old google+ endpoint which was shutdown years ago.

> googleapis.com/plus/v1

You should be using [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)

The correct endpoint would be.

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/{resourceName=people/*}
```

## People API scopes

These are the new scopes for the [people api](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest).

[image]

## Enable people api

The first thing you need to do is double check the Client id and the project you are using.  Are in fact the same as the one you think it is.

Then go to [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard)  for that project.  Click library

[image]

In the search box search for people

[image]

And select people api

Then click enable

[image]

Once it has been enable in the same project as the client id you are using it should work within a few minutes.

## PHP code

Assuming you are following the [PHP quick start](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/php) something like the following should give you the response you are looking for.

```
 $results = $service->people->get('people/me');
```

Comment: already enabled  google people api but not getting resonse

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.   If you are getting that error message your doing something else wrong or your checking the wrong client id.

Comment: @Dalmto "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token={$access_token}&key={$app_key}" this is my google api url is this is sufficient to solve my problem

Comment: Theres your problem that endpoint was for Google+ as I mentioned.  You should use [People.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)  which would be https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me.  Please check the edit on my anwser

Comment: with   "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me"   this url am getting error {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
can u explane what is the API KEY >

Comment: did you add the access token and the api key like you had on your original request?  You know it would help a lot if you would post your code in your question.   change  **googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me**  to **people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me**  in your call.  All you are doing is pointing to a different endpoint.  You still need to be authorized.

Comment: Please check the update on my answer.   I have include the code you should be using assuming that you are using the PHP client library.

Comment: first i post my code,  secound thing is am not getting what is the api key which key i place inside the api key can u explane something ?

Comment: "googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token={$access_token}&key={$app_key}"   <--- its the code you gave me that you said you where using it.   The access token and key you where sending before.

Comment: The answer to your question is that you where using the wrong endpoint.   I have answered that question and you should be all set now.    I think you should take a step back and have a look at the official sample.   https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/php  If you have any issues you should open a new question.